# Discord.js mod bot ban command not working

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

My discord bot's ban command isn't working and is currently giving me this error. My rols id is `853527575317708820`
I don't know what I am doing wrong so please help me out

Here is the command :

```js
Server is ready.
TigerShark Community#3557 Has logged in
(node:204) UnhandledPromiseRejectiontarning: DiscordAPTError: T
AEE RS
user_id: Value "<@!856413967595012127>" is not snowflake.
at RequestHandler.execute (/home/Tunner/TSC/node_modules/di
scoxd. js/src/rest/RequestHandler. js:154:13)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task
§5:97:5) :!
at async RequestHandler.push (/home/zunner/TSC/node
/discord. js/s1c/rest/RequestHandler. js:39:14)
```

Here is my code :

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'ban',
  description: "Used to ban members from a server",
  async execute(client, message, args, Discord) {

    if (!(message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.id === "853527575317708820"))) return

      let reason;
      const user = await client.users.fetch(args[0])
      if (!args[1])
      {
        reason = "Not specified"
      } else {
        reason = args[1]
      }

      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`${user.username} was banned!`)
      .setDescription(`${user.username} was banned by ${message.author.username} for: ${reason}`)
      .setColor("#f0db4f")
      .setFooter("Ban Command")
      .setTimestamp()

      message.channel.send(embed)
      message.guild.members.ban(user)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command has few issues in it.

The first being that it does not allow banning users with command if the user is mentioned, it only allows banning by user ID. To fix that simply do:

```js
const user = message.mentions.members.first() || await client.users.fetch(args[0])
```

You should also add check if the user is found, so right after you declare value for `user`

```js
const user = message.mentions.members.first() || await client.users.fetch(args[0])
if(!user) return message.reply(`No user found`);
```

Now if you allow banning both mentions and user IDs there might be a different `user` value. So I recommend editing your embed aswell to something like:

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`${user.user.username} was banned!`)
      .setDescription(`${user.user.username} was banned by ${message.author.username} for: ${reason}`)
      .setColor("#f0db4f")
      .setFooter("Ban Command")
      .setTimestamp()
```

This should fix majority of your issues, I recommend that if something is `undefined` in future or you come across any bugs in your code. Do some debugging by sending messages to console `console.log(variable)` or `console.log("This works?")`

Comment: Thanks, bro @NotTrixxie

Comment: but there is problem with id, can't ban with user id its works only mentions

Answer (score 1):

if you are using discord.js v12 you can do what the other answer said and get the user by mention `message.mentions.members.first()` but if you are using v13 that wont work anymore

the reason its giving that error is because you need to fetch the user by their id alone, so you can do this `client.users.fetch(args[0].replace('<@!', '').replace('>', ''))` to remove the `<@!` and `>` (mention prefix) from it.

Comment: You can still utilise `message.mentions.members.first()` on **v13**

Comment: @NotTrixxie ah yes your right it is still better to get the id from args though